# getting whitespaces when concatenating strings

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to concat a string variable into another string but I keep getting white spaces before and after the variable

`objwriter.WriteLine("netsh int ipv4 Set address "+adaptername+" dhcp")`

Output is the following

```
netsh int ipv4 Set address  Wi-Fi  dhcp
```

I have tried the following methods to concat the string also

`objwriter.WriteLine("netsh int ipv4 Set address "& adaptername &" dhcp")`
`objwriter.WriteLine("netsh int ipv4 Set address "" & adaptername & "" dhcp")`

Comment: It would be really helpful if you give me some resource to read up on how string concatenation works in vb.net

Comment: Replace this adaptername with adaptername.Trim()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY THIS**

**VB.Net**

```
objwriter.WriteLine("netsh int ipv4 Set address " &  adaptername.Trim() & " dhcp")
```

C#

```
objwriter.WriteLine("netsh int ipv4 Set address " +  adaptername.Trim() + " dhcp");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
objwriter.WriteLine("netsh int ipv4 Set address " & adaptername.Trim() & " dhcp")
```